# Possible to delete range rather than deleting the entire row, based on If Not VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to search for numbers in columns, delete the rows and shift all other rows up if they're not found, but it's also deleting conditional formatting and formulas so that each time it's ran, the cells which contain the formatting and formulas becomes less and less.

I've tried changing

```
.Rows(i).Delete
```

to

```
.Range("A2:M100").Delete
```

but this is deleting everything on all rows including colour fills and conditional formatting.

```
Sub NoMobiles()
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote GS")
    LRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
        If Not ((.Cells(i, 6) Like "07*" Or .Cells(i, 7) Like "07*" Or .Cells(i, 8) Like "07*" Or .Cells(i, 9) Like "07*")) Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'd like to keep the formatting and formulas from column N and onwards to the right and still shift the remaining row entries upwards without losing them. Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That doesn't work if you delete entire rows (you would need to shift only the data and move all the other data) would be a lot of slow data moving actions. I suggest to add a new formatted line in the end for each row you delete (eg copy). • Can you add a screenshot of your sheet?

Comment: Added thanks.  As mentioned I have formulas and conditional formatting in column N that I'd like to keep.  So in this instance, row 3 would be deleted once the code is ran but I'm losing the formatting and formulas on each line once the delete kicks in.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to add (copy) one formatted row (incl. formulas) in the end for every deleted row.

Comment: OK, thank you, I've done that instead :-)

Comment: Is your data in a table format? This should resize accordingly and copy formulas and formatting with your dataset if setup properly.